# Trouble encoding emoji's for web service in Android

Tags: android, mysql, utf-8, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm trying to send an emoji to my webservice and then receive that emoji later.

Everywhere I've looked, I've seen two solutions:
1.)

```
URLEncoder.encode(msg_text, "UTF-8");  
URLDecoder.decode(msg_text, "UTF-8");
```

and 2.)

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(msg_text);  
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(msg_text);
```

If I use StringEncoder, I can send "uD83DuDE0A"
If I use URLEncoder, I can send "??"
If I use both, in either order, I can send "????????"

I've tried altering the characterset in my mysql database to "utf8mb4" but  there is a possibility that I didn't do that right.

I also checked the documentation for URLEncoder to see if I could change "UTF-8" to something like "UTF-8mb4" but that didn't exist. I tried "UTF-16" but that gave me some weird unicode characters.

I've tried replacing the "\" in my msg_text with "\\" before sending it and that didn't seam to do anything.

I'm posting here because I'm out of ideas for what I could do. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by converting every character to a Unicode string, this eliminates any possibility of encoding/decoding issues, but it creates 6X the normal amount of message text storage. In my case, this shouldn't be a problem, and this solution is good enough.

This also eliminates any possibility of SQL injection.

Implementation: https://gist.github.com/nschultz14/a2334905eed3bf623b68642cc13899dc

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any libraries that try to convert encodings; they only confuse the problem.  Rather than trying to use `\uD83D\uDE0A`, can't you paste in the Emoji?

MySQL needs `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` for Emoji; `ut8` will not suffice.

utf16 and utf32 are there for completeness; don't use them.

Comment: What do you mean paste in the emoji?

Comment: Where is it coming from?  And where did D83D come from?

Comment: I enter an emoji into a textview, and when I perform textview.getText() it gets the emoji in unicode form. "\uD83D\uDE0A" is the unicode for an emoji that I tried to send.

Comment: Can you get it in utf8?

Comment: What is "textview"?  (Obviously I don't know the tools you are using.)

Comment: In this case I'm using android.widget.TextView and I'm able to receive an emoji from the TextView object in utf8.